# CURL API show data in a table with php and html

Tags: php, html, json, api, curl

The code does not display the data.
I try to display the values ​​of each ReportItems in a table.
The code does not display any error when I call it.
Please can someone help me? Thank you very much.

//The code does not display the data.
I try to display the values ​​of each ReportItems in a table.
The code does not display any error when I call it.
Please can someone help me? Thank you very much.

```
<?php
$url = 
"https://api.booker.com/v4.1/merchant/location/.../Report/DailySales?access_token={...}&date_from={...}&date_to={...}";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$headers = array(
"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key: {...}",
);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($resp);
$obj = json_decode($resp, true);
$i = 0;
$nw= array_filter($obj['ReportItems'], function($v,$k){
return in_array($k, ['Date', 'DateOffset', 'Discount', 'Discount', 'GiftCertificate', 'GiftCertificateRefund', 'Orders', 'Refunds', 'Services', 'SubTotal', 'Tax', 'Tip', 'Total']);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
$i=0;
foreach($nw as $k => $v){
$last = $i !== count($nw)-1 ? ','.PHP_EOL : '';
echo "\"$k\": \"$v\"".$last;
$i++;
}
$arrays = json_decode($resp);
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JSON</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="icon.ico">
    <meta name="description" content="HTML, PHP, JSON, REST API">
    <style>table, th, td {border: 1px solid black;}</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php foreach ($nw as $k => $v)  {    ?>
    <div  style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> 
<?php echo 'Date: ' . $v -> Date ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'DateOffset: ' . $v -> DateOffset ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Discount: ' . $v -> Discount ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'GiftCertificate: ' . $v -> GiftCertificate ?> </div><br />
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'GiftCertificateRefund: ' . $v -> GiftCertificateRefund ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Orders: ' . $v -> Orders ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Refund: ' . $v -> Refund ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Services: ' . $v -> Services ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'SubTotal: ' . $v -> SubTotal ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Tax: ' . $v -> Tax ?> </div><br /> 
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Tip: ' . $v -> Tip ?> </div><br />
    <div style="width:200px;border:2px solid black;height:20px;"> <?php echo 'Total: ' . $v -> Total ?> </div><br /> 
    <br />   
<?php  } ?>
<table style="width:100%"; class="data-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Date:</th> 
        <th>DateOffset:</th> 
        <th>Discount:</th>
        <th>GiftCertificate:</th>
        <th>GiftCertificateRefund:</th>
        <th>Orders:</th>
        <th>Refund:</th>
        <th>Services:</th>
        <th>SubTotal:</th>
        <th>Tax:</th>
        <th>Tip:</th>
        <th>Total:</th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($nw as $k => $v)  {    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Date ?> </td> 
            <td><?php echo $v -> DateOffset ?> </td> 
            <td><?php echo $v -> Discount ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> GiftCertificate ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> GiftCertificateRefund ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Orders ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Refund ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Services ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> SubTotal ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Tax ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Tip ?> </td>
            <td><?php echo $v -> Total ?> </td>
        </tr>
    <?php  } ?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Please can someone help me?
Thank you.

Comment: You are missing ; after the PHP code in the <td> and <div> lines where you echo your php variables!

Comment: <?php echo 'Total: ' . $v -> Total ?> -- wrong you need: <?php echo 'Total: ' . $v -> Total ;?>

Comment: Nothing...https://apitest.hamamomerye.com/SalesByPaymentType.php

Comment: Did you fix your code and added the needed ; after each php line before the ?> ?

Comment: yes, but nothing happened

Comment: I found the problem but i don't know how to solve it @Shlomtzion. Can you Help me pls?

Comment: What is the problem you found? Can you show what print_r($nw); returns? perhaps your values are arrays and not strings? Also is $nw an array or object? It looks as though it's an array and if so you should do : echo $v['Date']; for example.

Comment: The ReportItems is Array in ReportData Array and i don't know how to get and display values from array through array